# How to determine if a variable is continuous or categorical in Java?

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, classification

Im currently working on a k-NN algorithm, and need my code to chose either the Euclidean distance formula (for continuous variables) or the Hamming distance formula (for categorical variables). I have normalized all of the categorical variables in the data set to either 0's or 1's, but i can't seem to get the code to tell whether or not the data is one or the other.

Comment: Just use the standard Java API `java.javax.Variable.isContinuous()`

Comment: @paulsm4
 Can you please provide the correct path to the java API you have mentioned... this one clearly does not exist, so I assume it's an incomplete path.

Comment: The OP's question was absurd.  Whether a variable is "categorical" (e.g. "animal", "vegetable" or "mineral") or "continuous" (e.g. "weight" or "size") .. is entirely up to the guy who created the variable!  There's no way for the program to "know" this - in Java, or any other language!